# it there a better way to write the line in php?

Tags: php

```
 <div class="meta">
<?php echo  $submitted."pubblished in".$fenl; ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_path().'comp/'.$node->nid;?>">
<?php echo $comment_count;?>comment</a>
</div>
```

it there a better way to write the above code.

2,

```
function blog_gettag(){
    $terms = mysql_query('SELECT vid,name FROM term WHERE vid=2');
    $items = array(); 
    foreach ($terms as $term){
        $items[] = $term->name;
    }

    return $items;
}
```

could i delete `$items = array()`;  this line. thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. Let's say your `foreach()` loop doesn't get hit, and you delete that line. Now `$items` becomes undefined.

Comment: Also you if you're already using double quotes, then variables can be embedded inside: `echo  "$submitted published in $fenl";` and `echo base_path()."comp/{$node->nid}";`

Comment: does this code really work? AFAIK You can't iterate result of `mysql_query`.

Comment: onteria_,you're right. i happened to see an error"the $items becomes undefined. why if doesn't reach to the foreach loop, it shows $items undefined,if i delete that line. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not really, unless you count the short-tags, but [they are frowned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use).
2. Technically, it would be created automatically, but you should pre-declare the empty array, it should generate a warning if you did not.

**NB.** If you have two separate questions, they should be asked separately in future.

Comment: when it maybe generate a warning if i delete that line.thank you.

Comment: the questions maybe too simple to others. so i put them together :)

Answer (score 1):

What about one line?

```
<?php
echo "<div class=\"meta\">\n{$submitted}published in$fenl\n<a href=\"" .
  base_path() . "comp/{$node->nid}\">\n$comment_count\ncomment</a>\n</div>";
?>
```

You could delete `$items = array();` as long as `$items` isn't used before in your script (just don't return `$items` in case `$terms` isn't an array and the foreach loop gets called, as the situation seems to be at the moment). I believe you need to check mysql_query() examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

Answer (score 0):

It's syntactically pretty okay.  As far as I know, you could omit `$items = array();` but I find it more readable if you just leave it as it is.

Btw.: Don't you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc for your iteration? mysql_query returns a resource.

Comment: if `$items = array();` is omitted, It bring up a notice error.

Comment: Starx ,you're right.could you tell me why  It will bring up a notice error

Comment: I get no notice. But you will get a notice when no iteration via foreach is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div class=\"meta\">" . $submitted . " pubblished in " . $fenl . "<a href=\"" . base_path() . "comp/" . $node->nid . "\">" . $comment_count . " comment</a></div>";
```

You don't need to define array. But in this case ( foreach issue. Foreach loop requires an array as parameter to left side the "as". If you delete that line $items wouldn't be an array.It will be a null variable.So you will get a warning. ) it should be defined.